# Search mp3 collection for songs with a certain song length

Tags: find, mp3

How would I search a directory of mp3 files for songs between a certain length.  Ex:

```
findmp3 -min=03:00 -max=03:15 /music/mp3/ebm/
```

Would return all mp3 files in the `emb/` directory having a song length between 3:00 and 3:15 minutes in length.

I use Linux Mint, Ubuntu, as well as CentOS.

Comment: Please *always* include your OS. Solutions very often depend on the Operating System being used. Are you using Unix, Linux, BSD, OSX, something else? Which version?

Comment: added to question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First install `mp3info`, it should be in the repositories of your distribution (you have not said, so I assume you are using Linux of some sort). If you have a debian-based distribution, you can do so with

```
sudo apt-get install mp3info
```

Once `mp3info` is installed, you can search the directory `music` for songs of a certain length with this command:

```bash
find music/ -name "*mp3" | 
  while IFS= read -r f; do 
   length=$(mp3info -p "%S" "$f"); 
   if [[ "$length" -ge "180" && "$length" -le "195" ]]; then 
     echo "$f"; 
   fi;  
done
```

The command above will search `music/` for mp3 files, and print their name and length if that length is grater or equal to 180 seconds (3:00) and less than or equal to 195 seconds (3:15). See `man mp3info` for more details on its output format.

If you want to be able to enter times in MM:SS format, it gets a bit more complex:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

## Convert MM:SS to seconds.
## The date is random, you can use your birthday if you want.
## The important part is not specifying a time so that 00:00:00
## is returned.
d=$(date -d "1/1/2013" +%s);

## Now add the number of minutes and seconds
## you give as the first argument
min=$(date -d "1/1/2013 00:$1" +%s);
## The same for the second arument
max=$(date -d "1/1/2013 00:$2" +%s);

## Search the target directory for files
## of the correct length.
find "$3" -name "*mp3" | 
  while IFS= read -r file; do 
   length=$(mp3info -p "%m:%s" "$file"); 
   ## Convert the actual length of the song (mm:ss format)
   ## to seconds so it can be compared.
   lengthsec=$(date -d "1/1/2013 00:$length" +%s);

   ## Compare the length to the $min and $max
   if [[ ($lengthsec -ge $min ) && ($lengthsec -le $max ) ]]; then 
       echo "$file"; 
   fi; 
done
```

Save the script above as `findmp3` and run it like this:

```
findmp3 3:00 3:15 music/
```

Comment: This works nicely.  I modified your script to include the length of each song as it loops through the directories.

Comment: @acoder lol, I had that too at the beginning and removed it as unneeded :).

Comment: Btw here is my modified script: https://pastebin.com/ykYJiC6Q

Answer (score 3):

I doubt that there's an existing `findmp3` tool. Following the unix philosophy, it can be built from `find` to find `.mp3` files, another tool to report the length of each file that `find` finds, and some shell/text processing glue.

[SoX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SoX) is a commonly available utility to work with sound files (sox is to sound what sed or awk are to text files). The command [`soxi`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/soxi) displays information about a sound file. In particular, `soxi -D` prints the duration in seconds.

For each `.mp3` file, the snippet below calls `soxi` and parses its output. If the duration is within the desired range, the `sh` call returns a success status, so the `-print` action is executed to print the file name.

```
find /music/mp3/ebm -type f -name .mp3 -exec sh -c '
    d=$(soxi -D "$0")
    d=${d%.*} # truncate to an integer number of seconds
    [ $((d >= 3*60 && d < 3*60+15)) -eq 1 ]
' {} \; -print
```

In bash, ksh93 or zsh, you can use recursive globbing instead of `find`. In ksh, run `set -o globstar` first. In bash, run `shopt -s globstar` first. Note that in bash (but not in ksh or zsh), `**/` recurses through symbolic links to directories.

```
for f in /music/mp3/ebm/**/*.mp3; do
  d=$(soxi -D "$0")
  d=${d%.*} # truncate to an integer number of seconds (needed in bash only, ksh93 and zsh understand floating point numbers)
  if ((d >= 3*60 && d < 3*60+15)); then
    echo "$f"
  fi
done
```

Comment: of course, your soxi should be suppor mp3 format.thank you Gilles.

Answer (score 1):

Using `ffmpeg`:

`find . -name \*.mp3|while IFS= read -r l;do ffprobe -v 0 -i "$l" -show_streams|awk -F= '$1=="duration"&&$2>=180&&$2<=195'|read&&echo "$l";done`

`mp3info` oneliner:

`find . -name \*.mp3 -exec mp3info -p '%S %f\n' {} +|awk '$1>=180&&$1<=195'|cut -d' ' -f2-`

Or in OS X:

`mdfind 'kMDItemDurationSeconds>=180&&kMDItemDurationSeconds<=195&&kMDItemContentType=public.mp3' -onlyin .`

Answer (score 0):

```
ffmpeg -i  yourmp3.mp3  2>&1 | grep Duration | sed 's/Duration: \(.*\), start/\1/g'  |awk {'print $1'}
```

With above command, you can get your duration, So you can script to specify a domain for duration.
Also you can use:

```
find yourPath -iname "*mp3" -exec ffmpeg -i  {}   2>&1 | grep Duration | sed 's/Duration: \(.*\), start/\1/g'  |awk {'print $1'}
```

Replace yourPath with root of your mp3 repository.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question (though it's certainly a good starting point for the script that would be necessary), and you'd be better off using ffprobe's `-show_format` option, like: `ffprobe -show_format -i file.mp3 | sed -n '/duration/s/.*=//p'`

Comment: i do `apt-file search ffprobe` and i didn't any result on sid debian repository.

Comment: Strange, it is part of the [`libav-tools` package](http://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=ffprobe&mode=path&suite=stable&arch=any).

Comment: Are you sure? wich distro?i installed libav-tools, but it has avprobe, Do you mean avprobe?

Comment: No. He means `ffprobe`. It is not part of unstable. [Removed back in 2011](http://packages.qa.debian.org/f/ffprobe.html). E.g. for i386 [stable](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/i386/libav-tools/filelist) vs. [unstable](http://packages.debian.org/sid/i386/libav-tools/filelist)

Comment: avprobe is part of the libav project, which is a fork of the ffmpeg project (which is what ffprobe came from). There are some differences between the two, but avprobe will produce mostly the same output and take mostly the same options as ffprobe, so this answer (and my comment) can be used with avprobe too. Alternatively, you can [grab a static build of ffmpeg/ffprobe from here](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html#LinuxBuilds).

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9477756/1081936) and [here](http://superuser.com/a/507473/151431) for a detailed explanation of the ffmpeg/libav controversy.